# Is it good practice to internally call an API within the server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I have some codes as follows

```
// [DELETE] /api/v1/authors/:id
async deleteAuthor(req, res) {
  const author = await Author.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
  // delete blogs of the author
  axios.delete(
    `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/api/v1/blogs/author/${author._id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: req.headers.authorization
      }
    }
  );
  res.status(200).send();
}
```

By this, I want to delete an author and all their blogs. I know the naming of the uri is not good but is it overall a good way to code like this or there are other ways to do the same thing. I'm using Node.js and Mongoose

Comment: It's generally better to call an internal function that carries out the operation and does not go through your HTTP layer (as the HTTP part of things is just wasteful here and unnecessary since you're already in the right process and have access to all your shared code).  You can use the same internal shared function inside more than one route.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not a good practice, you should avoid making circular HTTP Calls (Not optimal, can unnecessary duplicate logic, and is more difficult to read your code)
What do I suggest? Following DDD & Hex. Architecture:

1. Have separated services e.g. `RemoveAuthor` & `RemoveAuthorBlogs`
   (Following the SRP principle of SOLID, one service do only one
   thing)
2. Your HTTP endpoints (E.g. `DELETE /author/:id` & `DELETE /blogs/author/:id`) will invoke those services.
3. If you need to delete the author and his blogs in the same request.

   a. Create a high service that calls to RemoveAuthor and RemoveAuthorBlogs (E.g. `RemoveAuthorReferences`)

   b. (My vote is for this) => The service RemoveAuthor remove from DB the author as the first step and as the second step will dispatch a domain event (E.g. `AuthorDeleted` that will be listened to by an EventHandler (E.g. `DeleteBlogsOnAuthorDeleted` who will remove the blogs of the author)

In my opinion, your services shouldn't make internal HTTP requests when you can use your own services, in this way, if the logic changes, you'll only need to modify the service

Comment: thank you a lot, your answer is really helpful. For the past couple of days, I've been trying to do something similar but got stuck because of some errors that left no useful messages.

Comment: Can you tell us where and when these errors are thrown? Are you using some dependency container to inject the services?